# Optimizing performance of an IO-heavy shell script

Tags: performance, bash, scripting

The following bash code, which reads from a single input file line-by-line and writes to a large number (~100) of output files, exhibits unreasonable performance -- on the scale of 30 seconds for 10,000 lines, when I want it to be usable on a scale of millions or billions of lines of input.

In the following code, `batches` is an already-defined associative array (in other languages, a map).

How can this be improved?

```
while IFS='' read -r line
do
    x=`echo "$line" | cut -d"   " -f1`;
    y=`echo "$line" | cut -d"   " -f2`;
#   echo "find match between $x and $y";
    a="${batches["$x"]}";
    b="${batches["$y"]}";
    if [ -z $a ] && [ -n $b ]
        then echo "$line" >> Output/batch_$b.txt;
    elif [ -n $a ] && [ -z $b ]
        then echo "$line" >> Output/batch_$a.txt;
    elif [ -z $a ] && [ -z $b ]
            then echo "$line" >> Output/batch_0.txt;
    elif [ $a -gt $b ]
        then echo "$line" >> Output/batch_$a.txt;
    elif [ $a -le $b ]
            then echo "$line" >> Output/batch_$b.txt;
    fi

done < input.txt
```

Comment: I'd rewrite it in `awk` or `perl`.

Comment: :) that's definitely my last resolution.

Comment: The only other suggestion I have is to get rid of the uses of `cut` and use built-in bash features to split up the line. BTW, you have some quoting problems.

Comment: For that matter, most ksh implementations will be much faster than bash, and those don't force you to give up support for maps.

Comment: ...but yes, **definitely** get rid of cut; that's going to be the slowest thing here.

Comment: ...by the way, I couldn't tell what the whitespace between your quotation marks was supposed to be, and assumed a literal tab character. Adjust as appropriate if that assumption was incorrect.

Comment: (to be more precise -- it's not that cut is slow when it's operating, it's that starting an external process is slow; if you were doing just two cut invocations and reading from them continuously, your performance would be fine, whereas one cut invocation per line is awful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   x=${line%%$'\t'*}; rest=${line#*$'\t'}
   y=${rest%%$'\t'*}; rest=${rest#*$'\t'}
   ...
done <input.txt
```

That way you aren't starting two external programs every single time you want to split `line` into `x` and `y`.

Under normal circumstances you could use `read` to do string-splitting implicitly by reading the columns into different fields, but as `read` trims leading whitespace, that doesn't work correctly if (as here) your columns are whitespace-separated and the first can be empty; consequently, it's necessary to use parameter expanison. See [BashFAQ #73](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) for details on how parameter expansion works, or [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for a general introduction to string manipulation with bash's native facilities.

---

Also, re-opening your output files every time you want to write a single line to them is silly at this kind of volume. Either use `awk`, which will handle this for you automatically, or write a helper (note that the following requires a fairly new release of bash -- probably 4.2):

```
write_to_file() {
    local filename content new_out_fd
    filename=$1; shift
    printf -v content '%s\t' "$@"
    content=${content%$'\t'}

    declare -g -A output_fds
    if ! [[ ${output_fds[$filename]} ]]; then
      exec {new_out_fd}>"$filename"
      output_fds[$filename]=$new_out_fd
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$content" >&"${output_fds[$filename]}"
}
```

...and then:

```
if [[ $a && ! $b ]]; then
    write_to_file "Output/batch_$a.txt" "$line"
elif [[ ! $a ]] && [[ $b ]]; then
    write_to_file "Output/batch_$b.txt" "$line"
elif [[ ! $a ]] && [[ ! $b ]]; then
    write_to_file "Output/batch_0.txt" "$line"
elif (( a > b )); then
    write_to_file "Output/batch_$a.txt" "$line"
else
    write_to_file "Output/batch_$b.txt" "$line"
fi
```

---

Note that caching FDs only makes sense if you have few enough output files that you can maintain open file descriptors for each of them (and such that re-opening files receiving more than one write is a net benefit). Feel free to leave this out and only do faster string-splitting if it doesn't make sense for you.

---

Just for completion, here's another approach (also written using automatic fd management, thus requiring bash 4.2) -- running two cut invocations and letting them both run through the entirety of the input file.

```
exec {x_columns_fd}< <(cut -d"   " -f1 <input.txt)
exec {y_columns_fd}< <(cut -d"   " -f2 <input.txt)
while IFS='' read -r line && \
      IFS='' read -r -u "$x_columns_fd" x && \
      IFS='' read -r -u "$y_columns_fd" y; do
  ...
done <input.txt
```

This works because it's not `cut` itself that's inefficient -- it's starting it up, running it, reading its output and shutting it down all the time that costs. If you just run two copies of cut, and let each of them process the whole file, performance is fine.

Comment: The original code forks six times for each iteration, while this version doesn't fork at all. On my system, the original code takes 24.1s for 10k lines, while this version takes 0.39s.

Comment: @thatotherguy If you're set up for benchmarking -- could you try the new version that caches file handles?

Comment: Oooh -- my first cut was missing a `-g` in the `declare -A output_fds`, thus making it function-local and not caching anything (but wasting lots of fds). Fixed.

Comment: By the way -- if the performance with bash still isn't good enough after making these adjustments, I'd consider / suggest porting it to ksh93, a POSIX-superset shell which also has all the requisite shiny features, but also has performance near awk's.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like my bash doesn't support declare -g. Let me try something else.

Comment: @Feng, the `-g` is only needed to put the `declare` inside the function -- you can move it outside the function and take out the `-g`. However, if you don't support that, you might be missing other features, so some of the other recent tricks (redirection to a variable, automatic FD assignment, etc) may fail. What's the specific version? Also, how many distinct output files are we talking about?

Comment: My was 4.1.2. I was thinking you were trying to cache output before writing to files. My input was billions of lines. Output files could be 10-100 files. However, if I cache them in memory. It can easily blow up....

Comment: @Feng, no, I'm not caching *output*; I'm caching *file handles*. Every time you do `echo "$content" >filename`, it opens a new file handle on `filename`, does the write, and then closes it. That's silly inefficiency if you're going to be writing to the same files a lot of times.

Comment: @Feng, ...so, to finish the explanation: `exec 3>filename` opens `filename` on FD 3, and `echo "$content" >&3` writes to that already-open FD 3 much more efficiently than `echo "$content" >filename` would. `exec {fd_name}>filename` is an auto-opening variant, available on new releases, that doesn't require you to track FD numbers yourself; the same version that added it also added support for `>&$expr`, which previously wasn't allowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I wasn't good at shell scripting. Learnt a lot from your code.

Comment: It did improve the performance a lot. I feel about 50x faster, but it still take unacceptable time to run through a file with 79936393 lines.... I feel there wasn't too much caching for reading. Any idea?

Comment: @Feng, no ideas I haven't already floated. As shells go, bash is a pretty slow one -- you'd gain some additional performance rewriting for ksh93. With the volume of data you're dealing with, though, you're probably going to need to end up with a non-shell language at the end... probably something compiled, or at least JITted.

Comment: @Feng, ...also, I don't know what you mean about "cacheing for reading" -- read buffering is the C standard library's responsibility here; it's not something the script has any control over.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your help. I just used my last resolution and changed it to awk:) Runs much faster.